# how to use microsoft blend buttons in windows form application

Tags: visual-studio, blend

I created custom button in blend but I don't know how to use that button in Windows Form Application
please tell me how to export custom button for Windows Form Application

Answer (score 0):

You could either right click on the button then > View Source and then copy the code.

Or, a better way, is to open your project in Blend, instead of having separate projects.